# I cannot print the last statement, that is which player won

Tags: python-3.x

**The problem**

Check the input. If it's incorrect, print the reason why. Also, limit the possible amount of pencils taken. Let's say that players can remove not more than 3 pencils at a time.

Here are possible errors and their feedback:

The initial number of pencils is not a numeric string, so it can't be converted to an integer — `The number of pencils should be numeric;`
The initial number of pencils is equal to `0` — The number of pencils should be positive;
If the input is a negative amount, apply condition (1), as the minus sign is not a numeric;
If the chosen first player is not `*Name1*` or `*Name2*` — Choose between `*Name1*` and `*Name2*`;
One of the players has taken the number of pencils that differs from 1, 2, or 3 — Possible values: '1', '2' or '3';
One of the players has taken more pencils than there are on the table — Too many pencils were taken.
If one of the errors occurs, ask for input once again.

Don't forget to help determine the winner of the game. The player who takes the last pencil loses the game. Print out the result at the end of the game with the line *Winner-name* won!

**The test:**

```
Example 1:

How many pencils would you like to use:
> a
The number of pencils should be numeric
> 5
Who will be the first (John, Jack):
...
```

```
Example 2:
How many pencils would you like to use:
> 0
The number of pencils should be positive
> 20
Who will be the first (John, Jack):
...
```

```
Example 3:
How many pencils would you like to use:
> 5
Who will be the first (John, Jack):
> JohnJack
Choose between 'John' and 'Jack'
> John
|||||
John's turn!
...
```

```
How many pencils would you like to use:
> 5
Who will be the first (John, Jack):
> John
|||||
John's turn!
> 4
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> 1
||||
Jack's turn!
...
```

```
How many pencils would you like to use:
> 5
Who will be the first (John, Jack):
> John
|||||
John's turn!
> a
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> 1
||||
Jack's turn!
...
```

```
Example 6:
How many pencils would you like to use:
> 5
Who will be the first (John, Jack):
> John
|||||
John's turn!
> 3
||
Jack's turn!
> 3
Too many pencils were taken
> 2
John won!
```

**My code:**

```
print('How many pencils would you like to use:')
pen_num: int = 0
first_player = 'John'
second_player = 'Jack'

while True:
    pen_num = input()
    if not pen_num.isnumeric():
        print('The number of pencils should be numeric')
        continue
    if int(pen_num) == 0:
        print('The number of pencils should be positive')
        continue
    if int(pen_num) == 0:
        print('The number of pencils should be numeric')
        continue
    pen_num = int(pen_num)
    break
print('Who will be the first (John, Jack):')
while True:
    first_player = input()
    if not str(first_player) in ['John', 'Jack']:
        print('Choose between John and Jack')
        continue
    if first_player == 'Jack':
        second_player = 'John'
    break

cur_turn: int = 1
cur_player = first_player
while pen_num > 0:
    print('|' * pen_num)
    if cur_turn % 2 == 1:
        cur_player = first_player
    else:
        cur_player = second_player
    print(cur_player + "'s turn:")
    cut_num = 0
    while True:
        cut_num = input()
        if not cut_num.isnumeric():
            print("Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'")
            continue
        cut_num = int(cut_num)
        if not 1 <= cut_num <= 3:
            print("Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'")
            continue

        if cut_num > pen_num:
            print("Too many pencils were taken")
            continue
        break

    cur_turn += 1
    pen_num -= cut_num
    if pen_num == 0:
        print(cur_player + " won!")
    else:
        break
```

**The Output:**

```
Wrong answer in test #16

When one of the players enters number of pencils, he wanted to remove, there should be printed exactly 2 non-empty lines

Please find below the output of your program during this failed test.
Note that the '>' character indicates the beginning of the input line.

---

How many pencils would you like to use:
> 5
Who will be the first (John, Jack):
> JohnJack
Choose between John and Jack
> JohnJack
Choose between John and Jack
> JohnJack
Choose between John and Jack
> JohnJack
Choose between John and Jack
> JohnJack
Choose between John and Jack
> John
|||||
John's turn:
> 4
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> a
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> 0
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> -1
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> _
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> |
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> |||||
Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'
> 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print('How many pencils would you like to use:')
while True:
pencils = input()
if not pencils.isdigit():
    print('The number of pencils should be numeric')
elif int(pencils) < 1:
    print('The number of pencils should be positive')
else:
    pencils = int(pencils)
    break

name = input('Who will be the first (John, Jack):')
while name not in ('John', 'Jack'):
print('Choose between John and Jack')
name = input()

while True:
if pencils < 1:
    print(f'{name} won!')
    break
print('|' * pencils)
print(f'{name}\'s turn')
while True:
    choice = input()
    if choice not in ('1', '2', '3'):
        print("Possible values: '1', '2' or '3'")
    elif int(choice) > pencils:
        print('Too many pencils were taken')
    else:
        break
pencils -= int(choice)
name = 'John' if name == 'Jack' else 'Jack'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).